# PHP curl cookie parsing a string

Tags: php

I'm having a problem in parsing just the right specific string from the cookies of the curl I execute.

This is my code in parsing the string from the cookie.

```
$cookies = array();
        preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:(?<cookie>\s{0,}.*)$/im', $page, $cookies);
        $cookie = $cookies['cookie'];
        $file = "cookie.txt";
        file_put_contents($file, $cookie);
        $token = explode('CSRF-TOKEN=', file_get_contents(realpath('.').'/cookie.txt'));
        $tokens = trim($token[1]);
```

and then before I include the variable $tokens to my curl post data is I tested it first by trying to echo if it works well but I get this output.

```
WHac0HdIKj7lEn7dzk8YyQAAANU;path=/;secure
```

I get that output as the value of the CSRF-TOKEN but what I only wanted to get is the WHac0HdIKj7lEn7dzk8YyQAAANU.

Is there anyways to parse this?

I hope you understand that. I'm trying my best to speak english :)

Comment: @AbraCadaver, Do you really still have to know it? It is actually pretty far from what I really just wanted to know and to my question sir.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'/Set-Cookie:(?<cookie>\w+)/im'` instead.

You're using `.*` and `$` which matches any character all the way to the end of the string, with `\w` it'll stop matching at the end of the word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution (since you already use explode):

```
$tokens = trim(exlode(';path',$token[1])[0]);
```

But I think there should be a cleaner and faster way (unless you save the cookie.txt file for a different reason).